# Get a simple string representation of a struct field’s type

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

Using Go’s [ast package](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/), I am looping over a struct’s field list like so:

```
type Thing struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 []int
    Field3 map[byte]float64
}

// typ is a *ast.StructType representing the above   
for _, fld := range typ.Fields.List {
    // get fld.Type as string
}
```

…and would like to get a simple string representation of `fld.Type`, as it appears in the source code, e.g. `[]int` or `map[byte]float64`.

The ast package [field type](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Field) Type property is an `Expr`, so I’ve found myself getting off into the weeds using type switches and handling every type specifically – when my only goal is to get out the plain string to the right of each field name, which seems like it should be simpler.

Is there a simple way?

Comment: Have you tried `theFileString[fld.Type.Pos():fld.Type.End()]`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two things you could be getting at here, one is the **type** of an expression as would ultimately be resolved during compilation and the other is the **code** which would determine that type.

Digging through the docs, I don't believe the first is at all available.  You can get at the later, however, by using `End()` and `Pos()` on [`Node`](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Node).

Quick example program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
)

func main() {
    src := `
        package foo

    type Thing struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 []int
    Field3 map[byte]float64
  }`

    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "", src, 0)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // hard coding looking these up
    typeDecl := f.Decls[0].(*ast.GenDecl)
    structDecl := typeDecl.Specs[0].(*ast.TypeSpec).Type.(*ast.StructType)
    fields := structDecl.Fields.List

    for _, field := range fields {
        typeExpr := field.Type

        start := typeExpr.Pos() - 1
        end := typeExpr.End() - 1

        // grab it in source
        typeInSource := src[start:end]

        fmt.Println(typeInSource)
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
string
[]int
map[byte]float64
```

I through this together in the [golang playground](http://play.golang.org/p/cMIGnaDK5x), if you want to mess with it.

Comment: Helpful and also unfortunate. :) The file business is way upstream in my program, gonna have to restructure.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `go/types` `ExprString`

This works with complicated types like `[]string`, `[]map[string]string`, etc.

```
import (
    ...
    "go/types"
    ...
)

...

// typ is a *ast.StructType representing the above   
for _, fld := range typ.Fields.List {
    ...
    typeExpr := fld.Type
    typeString := types.ExprString(typeExpr)
    ...
}
```

https://golang.org/src/go/types/exprstring.go

Comment: This is a better answer, `go/ast` stores the Type in the `Expr`, use `types.ExprString` to get it.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly what [Fprint](https://golang.org/pkg/go/printer/#Fprint) in the `go/printer` package is for. It takes any AST node as an argument and writes its string representation to a `io.Writer`.

You can use it in your example as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/printer"
    "go/token"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    src := `
        package foo

    type Thing struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 []int
    Field3 map[byte]float64
  }`

    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "", src, 0)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    typeDecl := f.Decls[0].(*ast.GenDecl)
    structDecl := typeDecl.Specs[0].(*ast.TypeSpec).Type.(*ast.StructType)

    for i, fld := range structDecl.Fields.List {
        // get fld.Type as string
        var typeNameBuf bytes.Buffer
        err := printer.Fprint(&typeNameBuf, fset, fld.Type)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed printing %s", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("field %d has type %q\n", i, typeNameBuf.String())
    }
}
```

Output:

```
field 0 has type "string"
field 1 has type "[]int"
field 2 has type "map[byte]float64"
```

Try it in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/cyrCLt_JEzQ

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this without using the original source code as a reference for simple members (not slices, arrays or structs):

```
          for _, field := range fields {
                 switch field.Type.(type) {
                 case *ast.Ident:
                     stype := field.Type.(*ast.Ident).Name // The type as a string
                     tag = ""
                     if field.Tag != nil {
                         tag = field.Tag.Value //the tag as a string
                     }
                     name := field.Names[0].Name //name as a string
                     ...
```

For the non-simple members you just need another case statement (IE: `case *ast.ArrayType:`).